# Footer below content, but not floating mid-air if not enough content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I got this code:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/z21nz89d/2/

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here comes some content.</p>
        <p>Here comes some content.</p>
        <p>Here comes some content.</p>
        <p>Here comes some content.</p>
        <p>Here comes some content.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>Some footer-content</p>
                    <p>Some footer-content</p>
                    <p>Some footer-content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Some footer-content</p>
                    <p>Some footer-content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

It's kind of the very basic of what I have, but you'll get the point.
As you can see the footer is positioned somewhere mid-air.
I could position it absolute and make it sticky easily, but for various reasons I do not want that.

I want the footer to be BELOW the whole content (so to speak, listed as very last), however, if there's not enough content I need the footer to be placed at bottom: 0 and left: 0.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. My first guess would've been to use JavaScript to see how much space there is and whether the site is scrollable or not.

Comment: What you are explaining IS a sticky footer. Not quite sure what you want. Sticky footer places the footer at the bottom of the content unless there is not enough content to fill the height of the window; then it's placed at bottom: 0, left: 0.

Comment: Then I indeed do have a problem getting it to work as it seems.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the easiest way I have found to make a good footer. Wrap everything but your footer in a "wrapper" div. Then set your html and body height to 100%, with a min-height of 100% on your wrapper. Next, you need to give a bottom margin and bottom padding to this wrapper that is the same height as your footer. It works like a charm.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/z21nz89d/7/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot in my production now. Thank you very much!

Comment: After a few years, this can be solved easier with flexbox as you probably know. See my answer for more info :)

Comment: This really shouldn't be the top answer in 2019 :)
upvoting for Flexbox/Grid

Answer (score 33):

If the **height of the footer is unknown**, it's best to use flex, something in the lines of:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

And for CSS only this is needed:

```
body { 
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
   flex: 1;
}
```

And you don't need to set display:flex to body, it can be a wrapper inside the body too.

Keep in mind this might not work as expected on IE (see CanIUse link below). It works pretty good for most now though!

[CanIUse link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) 
See [this link](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) for an example.

Comment: Perfect answer in 2020.

Comment: this is my go to

Comment: Thanks this is perfect for me!

Comment: Great solution! Didn't work out of the box for me, as I'm building a site with GatsbyJS, which generates some obscure HTML structure. I discarded the `flex: 1` and used `justify-content: space-between;` in my body wrapper. Does the same thing.

Comment: This is a near excellent solution BUT the ```min-height:100vh;``` won't take scrollbars nor the sliding address toolbar on iOS Safari into account. The footer will surely end up at the bottom of the _viewport_, but ignores the movement of this toolbar (top of page and scroll up) and still ends up behind it. I have yet to figure out a workaround for that very specific browser exception.

Answer (score 5):

Solution with flex position here: 
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 4):

You can use this responsive css code and it is working in all browser's and it can changed according to browser size when browser can resized.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/vneyjmka/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        Header is here
    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="content">
        Content is here
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <div id="footer">
        Footer is here
    </div><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

**CSS Code:**

```
  html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
    text-align:center;
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it the javascript way, you can achieve it with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/z21nz89d/6/

```
$(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var contHeight = $(".main-container").height();
    var footHeight = $("footer").height();
    var testHeight = windowHeight - footHeight;

    if (contHeight < testHeight) {
        $("footer").css("bottom", "0");
        $("footer").css("left", "0");
     }
});
```

Make sure to add the following css rules, the HTML, BODY stuff is very important.

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

You will also have to wrap ALL your context EXCEPT for the footer in a div with a class of, let's say, "main-container", that way you can test the height of the entire body vs the height of the content minus the footer, understand?

It's all the JSFiddle.

Just note this really isn't the semantic way of doing this. A pure css sticky footer would be better in my opinion. If you can't use one, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this can **easily be accomplished** with `position: sticky`. See [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.
>
> This value always creates a new stacking context. Note that a sticky element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism" (created when overflow is hidden, scroll, auto, or overlay), even if that ancestor isn't the nearest actually scrolling ancestor. This effectively inhibits any "sticky" behavior (see the Github issue on W3C CSSWG).

[Examine this pen](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/MZZVjw) for a working example.