# footer and change box positions

Tags: html, css

I'm busy with a project of mine (first project) and i have come across a problem where in my front page the footer sits perfectly fine but i have buttons on my front page which leads to other pages with not that much content on them and the footer is just under the content and not at the bottom, i thought i had tried everything but obviously not. Please if anyone could assist me i would greatly appreciate it.

Another thing which has come up to the positioning of box-links. How can i place them anywhere i want to?

```
  footer {
   clear: both;
   margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #111;
    }

.index-links div {
 margin: 16px 16px 0;
 width: calc(100% - 32px);
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 }

<section class="index-links">
  <a href="weather.html">
  <div class="index-boxlink-square">
  <a href="weather.html">
      <h3>Weather</h3>
    </div>
```

The following is a different page :

```
  <a href="https://www.yr.no/?spr=eng" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/yr.png" alt="yr">
    <div class="weather-links">
    </div>

   .weather-links h2 {
   font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: 900;
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 40px;
   }

  img {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px grey;
   }
```

Comment: Hey Caitlyn. Welcome to SO. Can you include your html and css?

Comment: First question potential duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671073/footer-below-content-but-not-floating-mid-air-if-not-enough-content

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I have added the code. Should i add anything else?

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted? It may give a solution to your footer issue.

Comment: yes, thank you i have gone through it thanks. It helped with the other pages that are linked to my front page but now the footer on the front page sits in the middle of nowhere cause there is quite a lot of content so it is needed to scroll down.