# How can I put the footer at the end of page without covering content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap for my project and I want to put my footer at the end of the screen when the content is not enough to reach the bottom. On the other hand, when the content of the page is bigger and I need to do some scrolling to go to the bottom of the page I want the footer to be just after the content without covering.

In the end I want the footer to have the usual behaviour, fixed at the bottom when the page it's too short and after the content without covering it if I can scroll the page.

Right now as I have my code it's fixed at the bottom of the screen and it covers the content nearly at the end.

My code is the following (don't mind the php):

```
<footer class="container-fluid bg-black mt-5 fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="text-center mb-0">
                <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                    <i class="bi bi-twitter fs-4 p-2 twitter_white"></i>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="text-center align-bottom mb-0" style="color: white">
                <i class="bi bi-telephone-fill pe-2" style="color: white"></i>
                XXX XXX XXX
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="text-center align-bottom mb-0" style="color: white">
                <i class="bi bi-envelope pe-2" style="color: white"></i>
                example@gmail.com
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle white_links" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                <?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "es") echo '<span id="es_flag" class="fi fi-es flag_icon_rounded"></span>';
                else if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") echo '<span id="en_flag" class="fi fi-gb flag_icon_rounded"></span>';
                else echo '<span id="cat_flag" class="fi fi-es-ct flag_icon_rounded">'; ?>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/index.php?action=change_language&lang=cat"><span id="cat_flag" class="fi fi-es-ct flag_icon_rounded"></span><label class="label_flags black_links" for="cat_flag">Català</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php?action=change_language&lang=es"><span id="es_flag" class="fi fi-es flag_icon_rounded"></span><label class="label_flags black_links" for="es_flag">Español</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php?action=change_language&lang=en"><span id="en_flag" class="fi fi-gb flag_icon_rounded"></span><label class="label_flags black_links" for="en_flag">English</label></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <hr class="m-0 p-0" style="color: white">
        <div class="col-md text-center">
            <p class="pb-2 pt-2 m-0" style="color: white">
                © 2023 <?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['association']." " ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671073/footer-below-content-but-not-floating-mid-air-if-not-enough-content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footer below content, but not floating mid-air if not enough content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671073/footer-below-content-but-not-floating-mid-air-if-not-enough-content)

Comment: I have my content pages and footer separated using MVC so I what it says in those discussions isn't what I need as I can't wrap all of my content at once

Comment: You have a <main> tag somewhere no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer doesn't move along when scrolling because when you use the class `.fixed-bottom` it applies `position: fixed;` to it; removing it from the normal document flow. [Read more about what `position: fixed` does.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#syntax)

Here's an example of the behavior you want. The first snippet is without scroll, the second with a vertical scrollbar. The third snippet is an example using flex grow versus an auto margin on the footer.

*Note, for it to work `html` and `body` need to be set to `height: 100%` (or `100vh`) using the class `h-100`.*

```html
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer</h1>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the footer moving down with the content when adding a `<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>` in `<main>` (nothing else is changed):

```html
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer except when scrolling</h1>
      <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

And an example [using `flex-grow-1`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) on `<main>` versus [using `mt-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/) on `<footer>`:

```html
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <main class="flex-grow-1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer using Flex grow.</h1>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```